# Trying to install Ms Publisher 97 but have no code to input when asked. Can I get round this somehow?

Tags: installation, microsoft-publisher

Trying to install Publisher 97 onto a new computer.  This is so old I have lost packaging that came with it and therefore have no code to input for installation.  I desperately need this on my computer.  Can anyone help?

Comment: if you need a viewer, there are tools out there that can read `.pub` extensions. but we cannot help you to bypass a serial validation.

Answer (score 0):

As Lorenzo already commented, we can't help you bypass the activation or give you a key, but I have a solution that could work.

What you need is one thing: access to an old computer where you installed MS Publisher 97. Then you can use [KeyFinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/), [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) or [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/products.html) (Thanks Ramhound) to recover the product key.

If you don't have a computer around where you already installed Publisher with your key, you are out of luck. All other solutions to install Publisher are either illegal or cost you money.

Also interesting is this [Link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090425085022AAVS8L0)

Comment: I advise against KeyFinder and ProduKey in the past I have found these tools do not display the correct product key for certain products.  A program that has never failed me is `Beltek Advisor` and is 100%.

Comment: I only had good experiences with ProduKey, but I wasn't sure if it supports 97' so I added KeyFinder. Can you provide a link to yours so I can add it to the answer? I can't find it through Google...

Comment: I did a Google search on the term `Beltek Advisor` and the first result was the correct website.   www.belarc.com/products.html

Answer (score 0):

It is **Belarc** Adviser, but other than that, yes, it works very well for this purpose -- lists all the license keys for any installed software.